# In an elementwise add() CUDA kernel, why is the stride blockDim.x * gridDim.x?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I'm learning CUDA programming and I having trouble understanding the striding in this elementwise addition kernel:

```
// performs vector addition
// a, b, c are vectors and added values are stored in a and b, while the results are stored in c.

#define N 10

__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    while(tid < N) {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

Here is a CPU version of this:

```
void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    int tid = 0;    // start from CPU 0
    while(tid < N) {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
        tid += 2;   // assume there are 2 CPUs
    }
}
```

I went through several tutorials and all of them start with this `add` kernel.

I don't understand where does the stride of `tid` comes from?

---

**EDIT**

Now I sort of get what does the value of the stride mean. I think it means that if I have **2** CPUs, when one of the two running threads finishes, I have to add `tid` by 2 because `tid + 1` is handled by another core.

But here's the question, is the `tid` in CPU1 different from `tid` in CPU2? I think they can't be the same variable and the values are stored in separate memories of CPUs?

Comment: Your edit is all about CPUs but your flags are `cuda` and `gpgpu`... And where do you have the CPU version from? Have you ever read something about how to parallelize code on CPUs? And if you paste code from a tutorial please add a link to the tutorial. Have you looked into the [programming guide of Nvidia](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#axzz4iMq8V9Ae)? It es very compact but imo easy to understand and does not start with a stride but with a more simple `add` kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CUDA programming model, computation is performed by "blocks" of "threads". Each thread has a thread id within the block and a block id. So, like in your example with the CPUs, if you launched your kernel with 2 blocks of size 3, you will have 6 threads:

- block 0, thread 0
- block 0, thread 1
- block 0, thread 2
- block 1, thread 0
- block 1, thread 1
- block 1, thread 2

the `tid` variable will be an overall thread id in the grid, combining the block and intra-block thread id's. In the example, note that the `tid` values for these threads will cover the range 0..5 exactly.

Now, if the 6 threads each perform the add operation on array elements 0..5, and now want to proceed to additional elements, we could advance their index to ensure every one of them gets a new and distinct index to work on, and that no elements are uncovered. A stride of 6 (in our example) does so: The threads will process 6..11, 12..17, 18..23 and so on. So the first thread will work on 0, 6, 12, 18 etc., the second thread will work on 1, 7, 13, 19 etc. and so on.

Perhaps the kernel would be clearer if it was written as follows:

```
__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    int overall_thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int overall_num_threads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int pos = overall_thread_id;
    while(pos < N) {
        c[pos] = a[pos] + b[pos];
        pos += overall_num_threads;
    }
}
```

As for your "CPU version" of the code - it would not work, since even if you had different threads (perhaps on different cores) execute it, they would all start from `tid` being 0 and advance the same way - unlike GPU "threads", each starting with a different `tid`. If you had a CPU function initializing `tid = index_of_thread_among_Workers()` and 2 worker threads, the first thread would work on 0, 2, 4, 6 etc. and the second worker thread (with index 1) would work on 1, 3, 5, 7 etc.